Epimorphism is equivalent to surjective using right-inverses.
I want to show that in the category of sets a function is an epimorphism iff it is surjective.
The problem I'm having is with showing that epimorphism $\Longrightarrow$ surjective. 
I've seen the proofs that show that if  $f$ is an epimorphism then im$f = B$. However, I proved the result differently and I would like to have it checked.
Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be an epimorphism. That is, if $Z%$ is any set and $\alpha^{'}:B \rightarrow Z$ and $\alpha^{''}:B \rightarrow Z$ are such that $\alpha^{'}\circ f = \alpha^{''}\circ f$, then $\alpha^{'}= \alpha{''}$.
Let $Z = B$ and consider the function $g: B \rightarrow A$ defined in the following way:
$$g(b) = \begin{cases}
a \ \text{if there exists} \ a\in A \ \text{such that}\ b = f(a)\\
s \ \text{if contrary}
\end{cases} $$
Here $s$ is a fixed element of $A$. Also, $g$ is indeed a function. What I did was use the Axiom of Choice to make sure that if $b = f(a)$ for some $a$ then $b$ gets mapped by $g$ to only one of the $a$'s.
Now I will prove that $(f \circ g) \circ f = id_{B} \circ f$. 
Both functions map $A$ to $B$ so we only need to show that for $a \in A$ we have $((f \circ g) \circ f)(a) = (id_{B} \circ f)(a)$.
So let us have $a \in A$. Since $f:A \rightarrow B$ then $f(a) \in B$, which implies that $id_{B}(f(a))=f(a)$. Now, if $g(f(a)) = a$ which means that $f(g(f(a))=f(a)=id_{B}(f(a))$. Therefore we have $(f \circ g) \circ f = id_{B} \circ f$.
Since $f$ is an epimorphism then $f \circ g = id_{B}$. We have shown that $f$ has a right-inverse. Therefore $f$ is surjective.

I understand that this proof is not as elegant as the one I previously mentioned. Still, I would like to know if it's correct. The use of the Axiom of Choice is leaving me a little bit uncomfortable with it. I also didn't consider cases where there could be empty sets, dunno if that changes anything.
EDIT: The main question that I'm asking is whether $g$ is well-defined or not. I'm not sure if I've used the Axiom of Choice correctly.

To cite from the solution-verification tag description: '"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.'

I thought I had used the proof verification tag, but for some reason, it's changing it to solution-verification.

proof-verification and solution-verification are tag synonyms. The rules applying to one also apply to the other.

Alright, sorry about that then. I guess that the main doubt I have about the proof is when defining $g$. Is $g$ well defined?

No, $g$ is not well defined. Consider $A={1,2}$ and $B={x}$, and $f\colon A\to B$ the only possible such function. You say you will define $g(x)=a$ if $a\in A$ is such that $f(a)=x$. But there are two such $a$. Is $g(x)=1$, or is $g(x)=2$?

P.S. Put the question in the post, clearly and explicitly, not buried in a comment thread.

That is where I used the Axiom of Choice. I guess that it isn't very explicit, but I consider a function that, in the case you mentioned, would only choose either 1 or 2.

You did not do this. You wrote a "definition", which does not define a function. If you want to use the Axiom of choice, you first need to set up a proper family and define a choice function, but you are not doing that, and you cannot come back later and try to do it ex post facto. What you wrote is wrong. Also, the fact that epimorphism implies surjective does not depend on the Axiom of Choice, so if your proof requires the Axiom of Choice, then that is probably a bad thing.

You wrote out a set of instructions. I followed them and did not obtain a function. You then write a fuzzy paragraph saying "and I used thew Axiom of Choice to mumble mumble gazpacho something to make sure this is a function." That is not a definition.

Alright then, but do you think there is a way to properly define a function $g$ such that the rest of the proof works?

Yes, but only by using the Axiom of Choice (and using it properly, not invoking it like a magic spell that automatically fixes any problem). The existence of a right inverse in generality requires the Axiom of Choice (in fact, is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice), and you should not use the Axiom of Choice here, because the fact that right-cancellable implies surjectivity does not require the Axiom of Choice.

Alright. Thank you. I will stick with the standard proof then.
